# Coding up a histogram without using packages

Tags: r, algorithm, statistics, histogram

if given a set of 1 million data records, how would I compute a histogram? It would be very helpful if someone could walk me through how to approach this and I will figure out how to implement the code, I want to do this without using any of the software packages that have histogram built into them

Comment: This is an odd question. If you really wanted to figure this out from the ground up, you wouldn't be asking someone to show you how. If this is some kind of homework question, you should be up front about that in the question.

Comment: Im not in school its not a homework question

Comment: It's making me remember a course in probabilities that I attended and where we learned how to build an histogram. But, it's in French: http://www-ljk.imag.fr/membres/Olivier.Gaudoin/PMS.pdf#page=18. Maybe you could google-translate it.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @shea that this is an unusual request, but I'll bite. The first step is to create some dummy data...

```
library(tidyverse)
dta <- tibble(value = rnorm(1000000))
```

A histogram is just a bar chart that shows how many data points fall into a bunch of bins. So let's create those bins as a new variable, `bin`. This code also counts how many values fall into each of those bins and calls that variable `n`.

```
dta <- dta %>% 
    mutate(bin = cut(value, breaks = 20)) %>% 
    group_by(bin) %>% 
    summarise(n = n())
```

Since `bin` is an ordered factor, you can create a barplot using bin on the X axis and n on the Y. You asked not to be shown how to do that part, so I'll stop here :-)